# How can I get rows from a table with the max value (all equal rows) for each different value of another row?

Tags: sql, android-sqlite

In an Android App I'm developping, I need to get info on a table depending on 2 rows (so with pairs) but can't really find a way to do it. How could I achieve that with SQL ?

/!\ The following is a simplified example as the real situation would be more confusing than it would help. /!\

So for exemple, if I have this table:
[image: SCORE_TABLE]

How could I get this result (the rows for the best scores for each category) :
[image: Wanted resluts]

I used to do it like this:

```
SELECT name, category, MAX(score)
FROM SCORE_TABLE
GROUP BY category
```

But I'd get this :
[image: Results]

When I checked for answers I saw solutions using sub-queries like so:

```
SELECT *
FROM SCORE_TABLE
WHERE score == (
    SELECT MAX(score)
    FROM SCORE_TABLE
)
```

But this would only work with one category, so I'm thinking maybe I could use some variation of this using a table with all the category-max_score pairs, like this:
MAX_SCORE_TABLE:
[image: MAX_SCORE_TABLE]

But I really don't see how, so if you have any ideas, I'd love some help ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should work, but pls check on the larger dataset:

```
SELECT name,
       category,
       score
FROM score_table AS tab1
RIGHT JOIN
  (SELECT category AS cat,
          MAX(score) AS max
   FROM score_table
   GROUP BY cat) AS tab2 
ON tab1.score = max AND category = cat;
```

Comment: It's exactly what I needed, thank you so much ^^

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you need is the NTILE(num) function. It divides your data into buckets based on partition. Your top 2 data from each category will get ranked 1 in each category.

```
SELECT name, category, score, NTILE(2) OVER (
        PARTITION BY category
        ORDER BY score DESC
    ) scoreplacement
FROM SCORE_TABLE
where NTILE(2) OVER (
        PARTITION BY category
        ORDER BY score DESC
    ) = 1
GROUP BY category
```

I haven't tried this by creating a table but this should help. Since `From` is evaluated before `select` we can't refer to the alias column name.

Comment: You may wrap this in a CTE and use select there to filter with an alias if you want.

Comment: Thanks but it's not what i'm trying to do, I want to get every rows with the max score of their category not just the 2 best scores. And I'm using Android's SQL and NTILE isn't available anyway.